# Occasional Blob not found error on a firebird database

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

I'm useing Firebird in conjunction with IBX (I know one should not do that but it's a legacy application I need to maintain...).
When running that application (an apache shared module) under heavy load
I occasionaly get an exception message "blob not found" - and that although the query was executed a hundered times before without any problems.

When googling for that problem I found that forced write should be enabled (which actually is the case) but nothing else....

The query by the way is rather simple. Just a "select * from" with a left out join attached.
The problem occurs when reading a Blob (subtype text).....

Comment: What Firebird version do you use? Did you check database file for corruption?

Comment: it's 2.1 and yes I checked for corruption.

Comment: What do you mean "I know one should not do that"?  Shouldn't do what exactly?

Comment: @wheeler: I meant that it is said that ibobjects is not compatible with Firebird.... But it works.... And the only Thing we are experiencing is the blob not found error occasionaly...

Comment: AFAIK IBO supports Firebird, in fact [IBO main page](http://www.ibobjects.com/) actually states: _Supports ..., all releases of **Firebird** and InterBase_

Comment: OHHHHH sorry - I mixed up IBX with IBO... so... need to edit my question in that regards. sorry for that!!!

Comment: That is indeed eventually helpful since my application runs on many threads and there could be blob updates the same time another thread updates the blob field. But shouldn't that be handled by the transaction support?? Note again. I'm using ibx (TIBQuery and TIBSQL) with the standard params set.

Comment: Could this be a threading issue? EG: what if you try to serialize these queries for testing?